# Is light text on dark background less harmful to the eyes than dark text on light background

Tags: technology, computers, ophthalmology

Most programmers (at least most of my undergraduate classmates) use light text on dark background (LTDB) and so do I, instead of dark text on light background (DTLB). 
And as we know, traditional books and e-books are almost unanimously DTLB, and some studies claims (such as the Skeptics SE post I linked below) DTLB is more readable.

But, which, DTLB or LTDB, is less harmful to the eyes? 
I found the opinion divides on Reddit or on Quora. 
As I am in my 20s, upon asking this, I am worried that all-day watching computer screen will cause problems of my eyes in my middle age, as also is the case of the modern generation.

While [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/are-light-on-dark-colour-schemes-for-computer-screens-better-for-programmers) is a possible duplicate, I think the answerer is potentially confusing two things, namely readability and harm to the eyes, and some of his wording is ambiguous that which he is addressing. 
I don't care readability: I find LTDB very readable. 
I want to know whether LTDB is indeed better or actually more harmful to the eyes.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made. Not that it is easier to read, or causes less short-term tiredness, but that it is less harmful to the eyes.

Comment: Oh I see... previously I did not understand the rule of Skeptic SE, and there is no guide tour. Then I agree this is off-topic, but I don't know where to ask this.

Comment: There are internet discussions for suggestions on both side, and some in Chinese, but there is no celebrity or authority. I think this does not best fit the spirit of Skeptics SE, and maybe I shall ask in Health SE, or will you migrate for me?

Comment: This question seems to have been asked [multiple times on UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53264/dark-or-white-color-theme-is-better-for-the-eyes)

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I have seen that, but it still focuses on "readability" rather than eye health. So as I see it, this is best to ask an eye doctor.....

Comment: @Aminopterin-The question you linked to asks about what is better for programmers working for long hours staring into computer screens. If you want to know specifically about eye harm (i.e. eye strain), you can view this-http://www.chrisdanford.com/blog/2012/12/26/of-small-fonts-blink-rates-and-eye-strain/ and this-http://www.eyemagazine.com/opinion/article/eye-strain. Also remember there is nothing like permanent damage or harm to the eye caused by DTLB or LTDB as mentioned in those links!